# Nginx how to serve all file under a location and its sub directories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was successfully able to deploy Rails 5.1 app to EBS, not the pack files are generated in the `public` directory. Somehow I think `nginx` needs to be configured to allow access to those resources. Currently the app is able to access `404` page which is also located there.

How can I allow `nginx` to access to access everything under `public/packs` folder. Here is the rule which I am using which doesn't seem to work:

```
location /packs {
  root /var/app/current/public/packs;
}
```

any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully deployed your rails app and it is working then I dont think there is any need to provide access to contents of public folder.

They are by default served by the server.
If you are accessing your website at `www.example.com` with nginx and passenger root as `/var/app/current/public`
you can just access the files in your public folder as:

```
www.example.com/file_in_public_folder.ext
```

or

```
www.example.com/packs/any_path_to_file.ext
```

Comment: Yes it serves but only the files under `public/assets` not the new ` public/packs` directory

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to show the files in the directory of your site (without an HTML page listing the documents) you can enable nginx autoindex for that directory.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html

```
# Allow browser to see files in directory
# Exact request URI matching
location = /var/www/path/ {
    autoindex on;
}
```